# react - pass function by props in stateless and run in function

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to call a function passed from a parent in react stateless component and run that function in the child (checkBoxhandleChange).
react do not recognize passed function (props) in side child function(checkBoxhandleChange).

I make a function for all of type components (checkbox, input, ....) in the parent and handle  all

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from "./base/input";

class Parent extends Component {
    state = { data: [] }
    handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        const data = { ...this.state.data };
        data[input.name] = input.value;
        this.setState({ data });
        console.log("handleChange", input.name, input.value);
    };
    render() {
        const { data } = this.state
        return (
            <Input
                label="  is active ?"
                require={true}
                type="textarea"
                name={"reasons"}
                value={data.reasons}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

child => **Input.jsx**

```
import {
        Form,
        Row,
        Col,
    } from "react-bootstrap";
    import "./style.scss";
    const Input = ({
        name,
        label,
        value,
        handleChange,
    }) => {
        function checkBoxhandleChange({ currentTarget: input }) {
            console.log([input.name], input.value)
            handleChange({ currentTarget: { name: input.name, value: input.checked } })
        }
        return (
            <Row className="my-input">
                <Col md={12}>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3 col-md-12" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label={label} name={name}
                            value={value}
                            onChange={checkBoxhandleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
    
    
                </Col>
    
            </Row>
        );
    };
    
    export default Input;
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `checkBoxhandleChange` passed to the `Form.Check` component's `onChange` handler isn't working? Or it's the `handleChange` callback passed from `Parent` to `Input` that isn't working? Are there any errors?

Comment: Here is the working example of your code without the react-bootstrap forms: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-lake-if7wg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @DrewReese handler is working but  i wand run some function in child

Comment: @HamzaKhan  thanks . but my parent function do not  recognize  inside function in child

Comment: Run "some function" in child? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you are seeing, so that we can inspect and debug it live?

Comment: can you paste your error so that we can have a better understanding of the problem that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to remove your `checkBoxHandleChange()` from `Input.jsx` and directly call the `handleChange()` function from your child file using the `props`.

```
import { Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./style.scss";

const input = (props) => {
    <div>
        <Row className="my-input">
            <Col md={12}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3 col-md-12" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label={label} name={name}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={props.changedInput}/>
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
};

export default input;
```

You can then edit your parent file as such by modifying this line `handleChange={this.handleChange}` to this `changedInput={this.handleChange}`